# Handle overflow

Tags: html, css

There's a markup, that looks like this,

```
<aside class="left">

  <p>Thing 1</p>
  <p>Thing 2</p>

</aside>


<aside class="left">

  <p>Thing 3</p>
  <p>Thing 3</p>

</aside>
```

What needs to be done is exact the same thing, but instead it  should be in one block, and when on `overlow` occurs those things should be styled automatically.

```
<aside class="block">

  <!--These elements should have to look like, like they're in aside.right -->
  <p>Thing 1</p>
  <p>Thing 2</p>

  <!--These elements should have to look like, like they're in aside.left -->
  <p>Thing 3</p>
  <p>Thing 4</p>

</aside>
```

It it possible to do via CSS?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
p { float:left; width:100px; }
```

you can change the '100px' to whatever you like. when the screen gets smaller and smaller, elements will be automatically change.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want the first two `<p>` tags to float to the left side of the container, and the second two `<p>` tags to the right. If that's the case, it can technically be achieved through CSS.

```
p:first-child, p:first-child + p {
    float: right;
    clear: right;
}

p {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}
```

I haven't tested it, but basically what it should do is float left the `<p>` tag by default, then takes the first two instances it finds and float those to the right. You might have to add some styling to position them correctly (for instance, negative margins). Or you could use absolute positioning left and right. The point is, you can select the first two of something with basic CSS (which should work all the way back to IE8).

Have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/4k5u8/1/

Is this what you meant?

I'd also like to add that it's way easier to position if you just add a container class to the `<p>` tags.

Comment: Not sure if this is just for me, but your current JSfiddle's result box shows up as if all of `Thing 1, 2, 3, and 4` show up stacked (If you don't exactly understand, please see this image at: http://imgur.com/PB1iN0E).  I have Chrome Version 34.0.1847.116 m on a Windows 7 machine.

Comment: @Burn_E99 You're right! I was messing around in the JSFiddle a bit more after submitting my answer and forgot that it probably automatically saved it.. Should be fixed again now, thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0):

So what's the problem? Add some new block's

**HTML**

```
<aside id="aside">
    <div class="block">
        <p>bla bla</p>
        <p>bla bla</p>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <p>bla bla</p>
        <p>bla bla</p>
    </div>
</aside>
```

**CSS**

```
#aside {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#aside .block {
    float: right;
    width: 40%;
}
#aside .block:first-child {float: left;}
```

Comment: The problem arises when you try to iterate via `foreach()` within that blocks

Comment: @djay Do you know how many "think" do you have or it can vary?

Comment: @djay You may also need to reevaluate your `foreach()` method. That could be easier. AlexPrinceton's answer is the best if it's possible to add the container divs.